# c# Grid View setting rows number back to 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row

I have this code here :

```
private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Question", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Answer", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Question"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Answer"] = string.Empty;


        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");


                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();


                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Answer"] = box2.Text;


                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

      //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");


                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Question"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Answer"].ToString();

                    Session["Question1"] = box1.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();

    }
```

And now i have another button call btnCreate . I click the add button to add rows in Grid View , means adding one row and so on every click  . After i click create button , i want the rows number back to one , for now , the rows will be stuck at the number of times i click the add button until i refresh the page. I need the number of rows to be reseted to 1 after i have click on the create button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can direcly call SetInitialRow() method in your btnCreate click event, that means you are binding a single row to gridview which mean number of rows reseted to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `btnAdd_Click1` method:

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows(1).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your same code and it works in mine.

---

Like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetInitialRow();
    }
    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Question", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Answer", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Question"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Answer"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Question"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Answer"] = box2.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        //  Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Question"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Answer"].ToString();

                    Session["Question1"] = box1.Text;
                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }
    protected void prevRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetPreviousData();
    }
```

---

I am sory sory if my answer is on wrong track depending on your requirement. Comment and queries are welcome. thank you